# Clicking to view the edit on a closed question makes it appear reopened

Tags: bug, status-completed, edits, closed-questions

There's a bug that's currently occurring (at least on [RPG.SE](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/)). It's pretty simple:

1. Visit a closed question
2. Let it get edited, so that the bar that says "an edit has been made, click to load it" appears.
3. Click that bar.

The "[on hold]" in the title will disappear, as will the "put on hold" notice below the question - until you reload.

Comment: I guess we've had a regression. That bug is from a year and a half ago and hasn't been that way all along - does that really mean this gets closed as a duplicate?

Comment: As far as I can tell, the bug was there all along, as I keep seeing people reporting it (see under "linked questions" on the dupe) are you sure it worked at some point?

Comment: Well... I'm pretty sure it did, since I haven't noticed it before now, but maybe somehow I really haven't loaded an edit on a closed question for an entire year and a half.

Comment: Yup, it's not really common to see it happening. :-)